# where to define constants in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, constants

In which file should I define application-wide constants that are specific to my cakephp app?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I define them in app/config/bootstrap.php

**Bootstrapping CakePHP**

If you have any additional configuration needs, use CakePHP’s bootstrap file, found in app/Config/bootstrap.php. This file is executed just after CakePHP’s core bootstrapping.

This file is ideal for a number of common bootstrapping tasks:

1. Defining convenience functions.
2. Registering global constants.
3. Defining additional model, view, and controller paths.
4. Creating cache configurations.
5. Configuring inflections.
6. Loading configuration files.

Complete manual goes [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#bootstrapping-cakephp)

Comment: Thanks.. the book says "This file is ideal for a number of common bootstrapping tasks... (including) registering global constants" so I guess this is the place!

Comment: As a side note, it doesn't have to just be constants.  For example, I use a dev/staging server, and so don't always want to trigger emails on certain actions.  Frequently I'll write a var in the bootstrap file that I use to switch on/off features throughout the app.

Comment: Since bootstrap.php, core.php, and database.php from the /config folder are usually not under version control - due to localhost/live differences in these files, I would suggest defining your set of constants in /webroot/index.php - or rather, create a hook there to include a new file you place in /config e.g. "/config/constants.php" - which ís under version control so all developers receive updates on this file. Include it within your index.php, e.g. just before the '!defined("WEBROOT_DIR")' line, or after where bootstrap has been included

Answer (score 5):

@travis:

i think its better to use the configs file (and configure class) for such dev/staging stuff

the bootstrap is more like the "general" more hardcoded stuff - all app configs together
the configs are the "variant" config arrays.

just my 5 cents.

Comment: Link to documentation of Configure class: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#configure-class
Link to example config file: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#PhpReader

Answer (score 1):

There is a another way to set constants in external file except doing it in long files like bootstrap
(When it's doesn't effect on Behaviors like editable Pdf constants).

It could be retrieved from view, controller or model:

```
Configure::load('PDF_CONSTANT_FILE'); 
echo THE_CONSTANT;

// PDF_CONSTANT_FILE set in  app/config/PDF_CONSTANT_FILE.php
```

Adding **$config=array();** to PDF_CONSTANT_FILE.php file at start is necessary.

Just for general benefit.