# Where to define Global Function or Constant in Cake PHP. Define Constant Dynamic

Tags: php, cakephp

I am facing issue to define constant in cake PHP like:

I want to define these constant from the Database.

```
define("APP_NAME","Test Application");
```

How can i access these constant Model, controller and Views?
How can i define global function And can be accessed from the Model, controller and Views?

Please let me know. I am new in Cake PHP

Comment: Does Cake have a bootstrapping file? If so, add it in there.

Comment: You should add `Configure::write('APP_NAME', 'Test Application')` to your bootstrap.php. You'll be able to call `Configure::read('APP_NAME')` in your Models, Controllers and Views. Please also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639564/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-global-variables-in-cakephp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858232/where-to-define-constants-in-cakephp/3858592#3858592

Answer (score 0):

The best way to define and use the constants is create a separate file and define all constants there.
like I have created a file "cons_variables.php" and call this file in "app\Config/bootstrap.php" at the end.

```
include 'cons_variables.php';
```

this file contains code like:

```
define('PER_PAGE', '1');
define('ADMIN_PAGING', '10');
```

To access the constants from database is not a good way.Constants can not be redeclare once they defined.
Even also you want to use constants from database than you have to create a component for that and fetch the constants value there.
This component can be use whenever you want by **$components** array or your controller’s **beforeFilter()** method:

Comment: There's isn't normally a need to use constants in CakePHP - constants make life harder the most obvious example being: testing.

Comment: @AD7six need of constants depends on our application complexity.

Comment: k, I'll see your "depends on application complexity" and raise you a "If you're using constants in CakePHP you're doing it wrong.". Constants are irrelevant in simple apps, and a significant problem in complex apps IME.

Comment: I agree with @AD7six - you should use Cakes constants since you're... using Cake